# How to BEST find a Error Modal Message in selenium

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, xpath

I am wanting to automate a certain process and in this process an Error modal popups, I want to use selenium to capture this modal which will popup in multiple events. I have tried to find by XPath, no luck. I tried to find by CSS selector, but it will only capture one modal in one process.

Here is the div:

```
<div _ngcontent-c25="" style="margin-top:17px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-left:10px; padding: 1px; font-size: 18px;    padding-right: 15px;" class="">
            Route is Pending Approval.
        </div>
```

[image]
This is what I've tried:

```
By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Route is Pending Approval.')]]")

By.cssSelector("#cdk-overlay-4 > mat-dialog-container > popup > div > div > div:nth-child(2)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath looks fine to me. Some alternatives :

```
//div[contains(.,'Route is Pending Approval.')]
//div[contains(text(),'Route is Pending Approval.')]
//div[normalize-space()='Route is Pending Approval.']
```

Also, use `ExpectedConditions` to wait for the element (assuming you want to click on it) :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver,20);
WebElement modal;
modal= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("one of the preceding XPath"))); 
modal.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the dom element has max z-index value?